# How to make bash stop tab autocompleting hidden directories

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion, hidden-files

Most of the time, I don't need autocompletes for my hidden directories.  In fact, that's the point of them being hidden!  However, annoyingly, bash takes these directories into account when considering tab autocompletion.

This is particularly annoying when I have the following scenario: a .svn foler along with a single folder that I want to traverse into by simply pushing tab.  (This typically comes up with deep Java packages...)

Is there any way to change the default behavior?  Worst case scenario I have to type '.' before tab, which seems like a no brainer for my usability.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just add this line to your `~/.bashrc` (if you don't have one, create it):

```
bind 'set match-hidden-files off'
```

And bash-completion should behave the way you want.

There are also many other options you might want to tweak in bash-completion. To see a complete list, [read the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html) ;)

Comment: Great!  Will accept after nine minutes, did not know that this was an option..

Comment: You can also put `set match-hidden-files off` in your `.inputrc` if you have one.