# Autocomplete dotfiles without typing the leading dot

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion

I've been getting close to `bash` on finding the really nice features of [Bash-it](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it).

I want to be able (or so I think) to key `ls file`, and on pressing <kbd>Tab ↹</kbd>, i get a list of dotfiles, or the single one that matches, as below, using the bash-it autocomplete, and other plugins and aliases.

```
~ ls Tab ↹
Apps/                                                     Music/
bin/                                                      notes
conky-grapes-master/                                      Pictures/
cpu_power.sh*                                             Projects/
cpu_temp.sh*                                              Public/
Desktop/                                                  snap/
disk_pct_used.sh*                                         src/
Documents/                                                Downloads/
vmpk.sh*
```

Comment: Are there any files that begin with a dot in the directory from your example? My bash lists all files if I type `ls [tab]`. Or do you want to change tab so it only lists "hidden" / dotfiles, then what about regular files?

Comment: if you have a file called `.file`, **you can't** autocomplete by typing `ls file` and pressing Tab. See: [unix.stackexchange.com/q/165495/307359](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165495/307359)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s a [Readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html) variable for that:

> #### match-hidden-files
>
> This variable, when set to ‘on’, causes Readline to
> match files whose names begin with a ‘.’ (hidden files) when
> performing filename completion. If set to ‘off’, the leading ‘.’ must
> be supplied by the user in the filename to be completed. This variable
> is ‘on’ by default.

As the variable is set to “on” by default, you should search for the line which sets it off and delete or comment it, e.g. in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
grep match-hidden-files ~/.bashrc
```

If you can’t find where it’s set or want to set it explicitly, add the following line to `$BASH_IT/lib/custom.bash` (if you’re using Bash-it<sup>1</sup>) or `~/.bashrc` (if not):

```
bind 'set match-hidden-files on'
```

<sup>1</sup> Bash-it overwrites the `~/.bashrc` when you update it, to keep the configuration you need to set the variable in any of [Bash-it’s custom configuration files](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it#custom-scripts-aliases-themes-and-functions). Bash-it doesn’t set `match-hidden-files off` by default.

---

Here’s the exact opposite question: [How to make bash stop tab autocompleting hidden directories](https://askubuntu.com/q/190771/507051)